# Should I use 'var' or 'const' when requiring packages in my modules?

Tags: node.js

Should I use `var` or `const` when requiring packages in my modules? Is there any difference to how the app will behave? Say, I use Mongoose — which is the preferred way and why:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

or

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Comment: If you do not reassign a value to `mongoose` use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) else use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: `const`   There's really no reason to use `var` in modern JS, at least in node.